# how to store a value of an HTML input in a cookie in PHP

Tags: php, html, cookies

here is the html code

```
<!

DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>



        <form action="test.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="pseudo">

            <input type="submit">

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

the form returns the value of the input in a page called test.php and the stock in a coockie but it does not work

here is the php code

```
<?php

setcookie("pseudo", $_POST['pseudo'], time() + 365*24*3600);


echo "Your name is " . $_COOKIE['pseudo'];
```

Comment: `$_COOKIE['pseudo']` isn't available straight away untill you perform a refresh (ie your php reads the cookie) or you manually set `$_COOKIE['pseudo']` at the same time of setting your cookie header.

Answer (score -2):

you are missing the **cookie name parameter** which is required to set a cookie. 
please see the below implementation

```php
setcookie("Cookie_Name", $_POST['pseudo'], time() + 365*24*3600);
```

Comment: As far I can tell OP is using "pseudo" as the cookie name.